# How to convert 3 type of dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a function, which has a paramater ( a string which contains a date ) and then the function converts it and returns it. In our company we have workstations with three different languages. We have hungarian, english and german workstations too. I want to read a date from the registry, but this date will be written into the registry according to the current regional setting.

So if the regional setting is hungarian, then date written to date registry is 2012.01.25 (YYY.MM.DD), but if i change the regional setting to german then the value written to the registry will be 25/01/2012 (MM.DD.YYYY). If i change the regional setting to english, then the value will be 01/25/2012 (DD.MM.YYYY).

Unfortunately i don't know which regional setting was used when the date was written into the registry, because it can be changed since the value was written into the registry.

This iy why i want to create a function which gets a date, and then converts it to this format: YYYY.MM.DD. but i don't know how to do it.

Could someone help me how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question refers to the Windows Application Registry, but your tags are for SQL?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are out of luck, because the same string could be a valid `dd.mm.yyyy` *and* `mm.dd.yyyy` at the same time. For example, `12/10/2011` could be interpreted as either Dec-10, 2011 or Oct 12, 2011, depending on the setting that has been used to create the string. If you do not have that setting stored at some place, you cannot do the conversion reliably.

Comment: @BRPocock: yes, in some part it refers to the windows registry. But did you read my question? "Unfortunately i don't know which regional setting was used when the date was written into the registry." And i want to create an SQL function for this  conversion.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: yes, this is the smaller problem, but i can ignore it, if can't be done somehow. The bigger problem is, if you want to convert a date for example with MONTH() and the month > 12 then i get an error message, howvere it is not the month, it is the day, it is just another type of date format

Comment: The problem you describe (trying to convert a value where month > 12) is relatively straightforward: a big ugly `if-then-else if-then-else...` (or rather, a `CASE-WHEN-ELSE-END`) chain can deal with it without a problem: just check if the number that you think represents the month is <= 12, and switch it around with the day if it is not. Figuring out the incorrect conversions, on the other hand, is more problematic, because it cannot be done reliably.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: i thought about this solution too, but unfortunately my SQL knowledge is not the best. Could you please help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this expression to convert your strings to SQL type `date`. This expression uses the `DD/MM/YYYY` format **only when it cannot use its default `MM/DD/YYYY` format**.

```
CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('/', val)=5 THEN CONVERT(date,val,111)
    ELSE CONVERT(date, val, CASE WHEN LEFT(val,2) <= '12' THEN 101 ELSE 103 END)
END
```

This expression should be used inside a `select` statement. I am assuming that the name of your `varchar` column containing a date string is `val`.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. I will try it soon. What's with YYYY.MM.DD format? I should just check it, if the 5th char is a . or not, and then return it?

Comment: @kampi Oh, I see, I did not realize it's actually a dot, I thought it is `YYYY/MM/DD` with slashes. You are correct, simply check the fifth character for a dot '.' instead of a slash '/'. You can check [this page](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx) for the list of available formats; the one with dots '.' is number 102.

Answer (score 1):

Are you managing this registry value directly or it belongs to another software and just trying tomread it?

If it's yours, then

A. if it is a string value, then simply format it before storing, to ISO format (yyyy-MM-dd), format or formatdate function will do the trick

B. if it is a binary value, convert the datetime value to double with cdbl and store that

Well, if it's not yours, then it's not your lucky day. I've done it a couple of years ago and I used the text around the date to make an assumption on the format ...

Comment: unfortunately the data written into the registry comes from a software, what we hava developed with an external company, so i can't modify it :(

Comment: Then I guess you have to approach it from process / regulatory perspective, like for example mandatory US English regional settings on client machines and then reconfigure this setting on all of the clients.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving those dates on a date type of column (`DATETIME, DATE, SMALLDATETIME`, etc), then it won't matter how it is displayed or under what language it was saved. If you want to convert a `DATE` to a `VARCHAR` on the format YYYY.MM.DD then you can use: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YourDate,102)`.

Comment: with this method i have the same problem. Try to insert this `select CONVERT( VARCHAR(10),'13/01/2010',102)` to a datetime column. You will get an error message :(